# Behat, Selenium and Chromedriver CI errors

Tags: 7, testing

I am working on a Behat setup with Selenium and Chromedriver for running Behat tests for a Drupal 7 setup.

I am getting:

> exception ‘WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError’ with message 'Timed out
>   waiting for driver server to start.

Above this error, i am also seeing:

> 21:46:42.198 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are:
>   Capabilities {browser: firefox, browserName: chrome,
>   ignoreZoomSetting: false, name: Behat feature suite, tags:
>   [railsonfire_5e8a4d2e-8ba4-4…, PHP 5.6.34]} 21:46:42.199 INFO
>   [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
>   /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/myorganisation/myproject/chromedriver: 1:
>   /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/myorganisation/myproject/chromedriver:
>   Syntax error: “(” unexpected 21:47:02.201 ERROR
>   [OsProcess.checkForError] - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)

I am running:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.10.0.jar 2>&1 &
```

to start selenium with chromedriver in my pipeline.

I am downloading and unzipping chromedriver like so:

> –2018-03-19 20:39:43--
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_mac64.zip
>   Resolving chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
>   (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)… 172.217.7.176,
>   2607:f8b0:4004:80c::2010 Connecting to
>   chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
>   (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)|172.217.7.176|:80… connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response… 200 OK Length: 5508030 (5.3M)
>   [application/zip] Saving to: chromedriver_mac64.zip
>
> 100%[======================================>] 5,508,030 --.-K/s in
>   0.04s
>
> 2018-03-19 20:39:44 (120 MB/s) - chromedriver_mac64.zip saved
>   [5508030/5508030]
>
> Archive: chromedriver_mac64.zip inflating:
>   /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/myorganisation/myproject/chromedriver

My `behat.yml` file used for CI

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
     filters:
      tags: "~@wip"
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      javascript_session: 'selenium2'
      browser_name: 'chrome'
      selenium2:
      wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
    # Should be removed once 
    https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/pull/311 gets into a release.
      capabilities:
        marionette: null
    # Remove STOP
    base_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
  Drupal\DrupalExtension:
    blackbox: ~
    api_driver: 'drupal'
    drupal:
      drupal_root: '${project.basedir}'
    text:
      username_field: 'Gebruikersnaam'
      password_field: 'Wachtwoord'
      log_in: 'Log in'
      log_out: 'Uitloggen'
```

Please ignore the `${project.basedir}`, this gets replaced with the phing build target.

Ps: Also note that locally all behat tests run perfectly fine.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: Could you please share your behat.yml file. Please recheck that you have correctly configured everything required.

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Ok. Have you started phantomjs before executing the behat. And I think we need to change the port of wd_host.   
   
Can you please try with below steps:

1. Change the port as 8643 instead of 4444 for wd_host
2. Open one PuTTY session and execute phantomjs by using the command phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true
3. Take new PuTTY seesion and Execute behat

Comment: Im not using phantomjs. Im using chromedriver to test JS behaviour. Isnt this usable on a CI?!

Comment: Ok. I have used phantomJS, chromedriver also suitable (port 9515 by default). Can you please look in to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537347/run-behat-chrome-headless-without-selenium. Also

Comment: Also I am including the extensions part of behat.yml here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Codeship, the CI provider that I am using, had a different version of chromedriver that conflicted with my setup.
Running chromedriver 2.35 fixed the problem.

Many thanks Aswini K for the effort provided though!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes on behat.yml file.

```
 extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            default_session: goutte
            javascript_session: selenium2
            goutte:
                guzzle_parameters:
                    ssl.certificate_authority: false
                    curl.options:
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER: false
                        CURLOPT_CERTINFO: false
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 120
            selenium2:
              wd_host: "http://localhost:9515/wd/hub"
        Drupal\DrupalExtension\Extension:
            blackbox: ~
            api_driver: 'drupal'
```